# Can Python be used as a command line filter in the manner of sed, awk and (even) perl?

Tags: python, command-line

Is there a Python idiom or cmdline flag that enable it to process lines from a file or stdin analogous to these examples (input is a .csv file; you want to select and manipulate specific columns, presumably numerical, for the latter two):

```
awk -F',' '{print $1, $3, $1+$3}' foo.csv
perl -F',' -ane '{print $F[0], $F[2], $F[0]+$F[2]."\n"}' foo.csv
```

One could do a lot of clever things with conditionals and regular expressions but I just wanted to illustrate the basic idea.  Is there any way to do this in Python without explicitly **open**ing files, separating records and then fields?  Some examples in Python that are brief and concise (if possible) would be very helpful:

```
python  ???  foo.csv
```

...not to put too fine a point on it:-).

Comment: I'm unclear on how you expect Python to process a file without explicitly opening it.  The basic concept of a [filter](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/filters.php) is that it's a compact text transformer that reads from stdin (although many have an alternate input-file argument) and writes to stdout.  Virtually any language that allows you to harness stdin/out can give you a functional equivalent.

Comment: @Prune I think the question is about the Python equivalent of one-liners, not necessarily written in one line, but the main point is the shortcuts for open, close, loop one chunk (usually line) of input at a time, assigning the input line to a default variable, split on delimiters into default list, change the input line, etc. At least some subset of -l, -p, -n, -F, etc Perl flags.

Comment: @Timur Shtatland is spot on; that is exactly the sense in which I meant.

Comment: See also: `pyp`: https://github.com/hauntsaninja/pyp/blob/master/README.md , although it has only a limited set of features, compared to `awk` and `perl` one-liners.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike awk and Perl, Python does not offer an option to open files specified in the arguments and iterate through the lines in the files for quick one-liners.

Instead, you can redirect the content of the input files to Python's standard input, and do a one-liner like this:

```
python -c 'for a, _, b in (map(int, l.split(",")) for l in __import__("sys").stdin): print(a, b, a + b)' < foo.csv
```

Comment: Of course, while you *can* do this, you probably wouldn't *want to* unless you didn't know or didn't have access to any more convenient tools.

Comment: The `fileinput` module in the standard library offers a mostly reasonable skeleton for reading command-line files line by line, though the surrounding language is not particularly suitable for one-liners.

Answer (score -1):

you can execute `bash` in python, use `os.system()` function. such as,

```py
import os
cmd = """awk -F',' '{print $1, $3, $1+$3}' foo.csv > result.txt"""
os.system(cmd)
```

it's don't like `python  ???  foo.csv`, it must create a python file.